# How to do click chrome extension icon to go the option page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension, I want to click the chrome extension icon to go the option page, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your manifest file you can keep icons for the chrome extension icons as

```
"browser_action": {
          "default_icon": {                    // optional
            "16": "images/icon16.png",           // optional
            "24": "images/icon24.png",           // optional
            "32": "images/icon32.png"            // optional
          }
    }
```

But there should be no `popup.html` file and also no declaration for `popup.html` in the `browser_action` key.

Now create your background scripts file and add the below code to open `options page` by clicking on the browser action(chrome extension icon)

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
     chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage(() => console.log('options page opened'))
   })
```

Also make sure you have mentioned the `options_page` key in the manifest.json

You can find more details on the [documention](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-openOptionsPage) itself.

Comment: can I ask another question? how debug the background scripts?

Comment: You can use console logs for your background scripts, but remember your logs would not appear in the current tab's console but you should open developer console of the chrome extension.

You should open chrome://extensions and then in your extension card, click on the background page. Then the opened devtools you will be able to check console logs from background.js file.